# Check if a field s empty in a database in android

Tags: android, sql-server

i am making an application and i want to check if a field in the db is empty or not, i used user.equals("") and user.equals(null) and i even used user.equals("NULL") and it is not wokring.
what should i write?

Comment: user is a String i assume?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TextUtils.isEmpty(user)` which is part of the Android `android.text` package or you can do a manual check yourself:

```
if(user != null && !user.trim().equals("") && !user.equalsIgnoreCase("null")){
     //.. use the user value
}
```

What you check all depends on how you use your database.

Do you insert an empty String if the value is null?

Do you save the word "null" or "Null" if you don't have a value?

Comment: actually i used "NULL" because it is set by default in the database. Thank you!!